# mod_rewrite with spaces in the urls

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I need to set up some RewriteRules to redirect a URL which has a space in it. I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^article/with%20spaces.html$ /article/without_spaces.html [R=301,L]
```

... but it doesn't work. Putting in a space instead of %20 causes a 500 Internal Server Error. How do I add a space?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try putting a \ in front of your space to escape it.

```
RewriteRule ^article/with\ spaces.html$ /article/without_spaces.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: cheers! I shoulda figured it'd be something simple like that.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to avoid the complexity of escaping each space (e.g. if you plan to have this file automatically generated), you can simply use quotes:

```
RewriteRule "^article/with spaces.html$" /article/without_spaces.html [R=301,L]
```

Furthermore, these quotes can be used to encase any one expected argument:

```
RewriteRule "^article/with spaces.html$" "/article/without_spaces.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 13):

You can just escape the space with a \

```
RewriteRule ^article/with\ spaces.html$ /article/without_spaces.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
RewriteRule ^article/with[\ |%2520]spaces.html$ /article/without_spaces.html [R=301,L]
```

The first option replaces a space while the second replaces hard coded %20 in the url.

Comment: This should have got top votes. But alas! Timing depends the votes.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I've found a solution: use the regex style to show a space:

```
RewriteRule ^article/with\sspaces.html$ ...
```

Though, I suspect that this would match all the other whitespace characters too (tabs, etc), but I don't think it's going to be much of a problem.