# Apache - Redirect 301 pdf to pdf with spaces ( binary file )

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

What I want:

> To 301 redirect /file_new.pdf to
>   /file new.pdf ( %20 aka space between
>   file and new )

I'm aware that:

- I can rely on RewriteRule 301 which uses mod_rewrite, using a solution from this thread: @ [mod_rewrite with spaces in the urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410811/modrewrite-with-spaces-in-the-urls)
- I can rename the file to not include spaces and replace them with dashes/underscores

However, I'm personally curious as to how one would do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
Redirect 301 /file_new.pdf http://sitename.com/file\ new.pdf
```

The conf file parser throws an error when I invoke the configtest:

> Redirect takes two or three arguments,
>   an optional status, then document to
>   be redirected and destination URL

**Edit:** Apparently the mod_rewrite nor Redirect 301 methods are working for me, possibly because for whatever reason they aren't applying because the file actually exists in that location.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/sitename_com
ServerName site.local
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /pdf/file_new.pdf http://site.local/pdf/file%20new.pdf
RewriteRule ^/pdf/file_new.pdf http://site.local/pdf/file\ new.pdf
RewriteLog "/www/rewrite.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

In rewrite.log, it tries to match the pattern to each respective uri / http request.. I think something is taking control before it even gets to the mod_alias/mod_rewrite stuff.

So to sum it up, it goes directly to file_new.pdf in the browser and doesn't 301. I'm positive that `alias` and `rewrite` are enabled. My apache version is 2.2.

Comment: Hm. Just occurred to me I could probably hardcode the %20 in there.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Hard code the `%20`.

Comment: And if you have array of get parameters http://site.local/?param[]=1&param[]=2 do not forget to encode [] to %5B%5D too -> http://site.local/?param%5B%5D=1&param%5B%5D=2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `Redirect` is actually part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite.  i'm glad the %20 worked and you can also use quotes to tell apache that the path that includes the space is the URL to redirect to and not two separate items:

```
Redirect 301 /pdf/file_new.pdf "http://site.local/pdf/file new.pdf"
```

Comment: I'm aware `Redirect` is part of `mod_alias` as I initially tagged it for mod-alias, it actually didn't work for whatever reason, perhaps something in my Virtualhost? I didn't really tinker around too much with the default httpd.conf, this is on a fresh Lenny debian box. I'll try your method and see if it works.