# Spaces in URL for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

I have tried multiple different rewrites and none of them are working.

This did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014\sLR.pdf http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf
```

This did not work either:

```
Redirect /images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014 LR.pdf http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf [NE]
```

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Based on all the posts related to this subject on here I thought I could figure it out but it's just not working for me.

**UPDATE 3:**

```
 #  mod_rewrite in use
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteRule ^images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014\ LR\.pdf$ http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf [L,NC,NE,R=302]
    ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
    ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
    ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
    #
    # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
    # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
    #
    #
    ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410811/mod-rewrite-with-spaces-in-the-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems:

1. You are mixing up `mod_rewrite` syntax with `mod_alias`
2. Leading forward slash is not matched in URI in `RewriteRule in`.htaccess`
3. Space needs to be escaped or quoted

This rule should work in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014\ LR\.pdf$ http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how things should be used. I tried this and it did not work. I have posted my updated code above. Thanks

Comment: You need to place this suggested rule before `########## Begin` line.

Comment: Tried that, did not work as well. Updated code above. UPDATE 2

Comment: Clarify `did not work`!! What URL did you enter in browser and what error did you get?

Comment: oldsite.divalsafety.com/images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014 LR.pdf is the link in the browser which actually went to this site instead of being redirected to http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf

Comment: Tried the updated rule and got the same behavior still went to the old link and did not redirect. I have updated my code above as well. Update 3.

Comment: When I entered `oldsite.divalsafety.com/images/stories/emailsig/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014 LR.pdf` in my browser it got redirected to: `http://www.divalsafety.com/images/Catalogs/DiVal_Hand_Protection_Catalog_2014_LR.pdf`. Open your request in a new browser.

Comment: That was it I had to clear my cache! Thanks for showing me the logic behind it so I can manage going forward! Marked as answer.