# htacccess - Rewrite file with spaces to another file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Unfortunately, both files contain spaces.

Old one: `files/Menu 202018.pdf`
New one: `files/Dworek karta 2023.pdf`

I've tried this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "files/Menu 202018.pdf" /files/Dworek%20karta%202023.pdf
```

As well as just with `Redirect` but this directive gives me `Too Many Redirects` error and in the address bar I see repeated `files/files/files/files` with the old name anyway.

I tried normal redirection as well

```
RewriteRule ^files/Menu\s202018\.pdf$ /files/Dworek%20karta%202023.pdf [L,R=301]
```

But this one doesn't have any effect. How can I make it to work, considering both files have spaces in their names? The new one I could potentially change but the old one has to stay with spaces as that URL already exists out there.

Comment: Can't see why that RewriteRule version should not work, https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=eef45560-bd7e-49d1-88b9-ddf0225227da

Comment: I can't understand whether `%20` go to the engine or not? I mean, even when we type spaces in the URL, isn't it Chrome that encodes it to %20. I tested it with `\s` or `[\s]` and it says rule not met

Comment: Yes, the browser will apply URL encoding if necessary - but at the time this "reaches" the RewritRule, the URL path has been %-decoded again already. (In https://stackoverflow.com/q/410811/1427878, the solutions also match on the already decoded path.)

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions (found those topics before). The tool you provided still says  invalid rule even if I quote the original url and leave spaces as they were before.

Comment: The tool does not appear to do the URL decoding, as Apache actually would. If you change the input URL to contain a space in that place instead of %20, the rule works in there.

Comment: Presumably you have more than just this single rule in your .htaccess? Then you should show us the whole thing, so that we can see it in context.

Comment: Okay it worked, thanks!